Bend two bones to make oval like shape
I have a simple plane that is divided in half and connected one bone to each side like this:

I would like to "bend" the mesh/ bones (preferably with a modifier) to get this oval like shape (when viewed from the side):

It's important, that the edges at the top and bottom meet.
So I would rotate the top bone 180°, but then they just sit on top of each other, but need to be bend outside in the middle.
Do you think this is even possible with bones? Of course I would need to subdivide the planes, this is just for illustration purpose to not make it over complicated.
The overall goal is to model a kind of box like this based on the diecut and deform it to it's final form.


What is the final form ?

@Hadriscus Like the last image shown. Hard to describe. It's called a "pillow box"

You could create a chain of bones with an IK constraint at its end (3) and a controller bone (4):

Disable the Deform option of the controller bone, segment the bones 1, 2 and 3, parent the mesh With Empty Groups and assign each vertex to the correcct vertex group. To deform the mesh, move both the first bone and the controller bone:

File: 
Another solution would be to use shapekeys:


Thank you very much! Could you maybe share the blend file? I don't have a lot of experience with IK, so I can't completely recreate it

sure here it is: 

Thank you very much! But I'm still not able to move them like you did. What move "command" do you use? I see that you highlighted every bone. But none of what I'm doing deforms the mesh like yours :(

If you don't know anything about armatures you should follow some tutorials, if it's too complicated, maybe use shapekeys instead of armature to deform your shape?

I'v edited my answer to show what shapekeys would give

Thanks. I had some more time to look at the file correctly. I just noticed that you set keyframes for that movement. I was wondering how you did all these folding with just controlling a single bone/ two bones, thats why I was asking how you control it like that. But now everything is clear how you moved it and how the mesh gets folded. Thanks again :)

I move several bones, the first, fourth and the ones on the side, but you could create a controller for all these bones

Yeah, that wasn't visible for me at first glance, I thought you used some sort of magic to move everything in one go to "build" the box.

To bend something, you would need geometry! And you can either archive that nondestructive by using a subdivision modifier, or edit the geometry directly - depending on your use case. From what it looks by your description, you plan to model this envelope without any niche case in mind; you do not need bones for it, it appears to be a standard mesh job. For that, edit the geometry directly by subdividing the rectangle a couple times along the main axis (Ctrl+R and scroll):
Click to confirm, and do it on the other half aswell. I used 8 cuts (you see it on the top bar)
Then, you use the edge selection [2 key] to make this selection of the end loops:
Change the pivot point to individual origins. [period key]
Enable Proportional Editing mode [O (Oh, not zero) key] to enable proportional editing; this will smooth out your next operation: pinching the end loops by scaling them down to zero, and using mousewheel to change the radius of influence. You can change the proportional editing interpolation curve to your liking at the top bar of the 3D view.

Then you do the same on the Z-axis, you select the center loop, and use the proportional editing to influence the entire shape in a soft downards curve.
Again, the falloff curve options might help you with this, either sharp or sphere falloff might fit better than the smooth one.
I hope that helps!

I forgot to add, you might want to run a [M -> merge by distance] to remove the doubled vertices at the end points after the scaling to zero, if you don't have autoweld already turned on

To me the question reads as if he wants to make a deformation animation: "The overall goal is to model a kind of box like this based on the diecut and deform it to it's final form." But you just showed how to model the end result. I might be wrong of course.

Thanks @ak97! Yes @GordonBrinkmann it totally right. I know that this shape is possible without bones, yet even easier to make without them. But I would like to use bones to open and close the box as needed and in the long term create some sort of animation of the box "folding itself".
